# поломался внешний вид панели администратора django при загрузке проекта в pythinanywhere

Tags: django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что надо делать? откуда исходит ошибка?

Comment: Забыли про collectstatic наверное?

Comment: ?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting. происходит вот это

Comment: Вот значит исправляйте эту ошибку в настройках

Comment: от души душевно в душу